# Logstash mutate remove field name 'JSON'

Tags: mongodb, logstash, elk, logstash-filter

I am trying to remove a field name "JSON" in my mongoDB record, while dumping in ELK. But it is not working, may be the case of reserve keyword.

Below is the document structure:

```
"date" : <date>,
"name" : "xyz",
"JSON" : <JSON String>
```

I wan to remove JSON field. I already tried to rename this field and then remove that also didn't help.

Below is the filter code with rename:

```
mutate {
    rename => { 'JSON' => "data" }
    remove_field => ["data"]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's nothing special about the string `JSON` as a field name or reserved keyword. Could you update the question with an actual example event?

Comment: You can simplify your existing filter code to just `mutate { remove_field => "JSON" }`. Logstash should run `rename` before `remove_field`, so I don't think it will make a difference, but it be more readable.